Apache Superset CountyMap Zoom
I have created a countymap chart in a dashboard I have prepared. I show data for 6 provinces on the map of Turkey. What I want to do is to zoom in with the 6 I show, not the whole map of Turkey.
This is the chart that appears now, but I want it to be smaller and only the cities I specify to appear zoomed in.
Normally the chart is like this
I want this
I could not find this information in the documentation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I didn't put it here because the codes are too long, I'm adding a link.
ReactCountryMap.jsx: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/plugins/legacy-plugin-chart-country-map/src/ReactCountryMap.jsx
CountryMap.js: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/plugins/legacy-plugin-chart-country-map/src/CountryMap.js
CountryMap.css:  https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/plugins/legacy-plugin-chart-country-map/src/CountryMap.css
